# Common Authentication Between Different Rails Apps

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, forem

I have an existing rails app which is running on mongoDB and devise for authentication. Now i want to configure an open source forum (forem) at the subdomain of my app.

All i want is the common authentication for both of these. If my users are logged in my main_app then click on forum then they should don't need to sign in again for the forum.

I could have integrate the forum directly with same User model but the problem is my app is using mongoDB and the forum is built up on ActiveRecord.

So now both apps have their independent databases. What is the best approach to merge their authentication and every request from forum app is authenticated using my main_app (running on mongoDB) ??

Answer (score 0):

Make an authentication api in the Rails app and let forum call it for authentication instead of managing it's own users